# Navigate user to click on an app in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is there any way to navigate a user to click on an app from a test class. My apex class requires user to click on any app from app launcher or refresh the home page of specific apps. How can I achieve this in test class?

Comment: Could you share the code you are trying to test ? It is too obscure to provide any help currently.

Comment: I am using UserAppInfo object to fetch and store it in another object but UserAppInfo requires user to select an app for its data to populate

Comment: You don't want to share some code ? From what I understand you might just have to create a record of UserAppInfo. Is it similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028554/test-class-coverage-for-apex-controller)